# after login, redirect to last visited page of the user's last session?

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I have a login form.
I want that when a user login in its account then he gets
redirected to the last page that he visited before logging out
in his last signed in session.

Plz help me with code and ideas since i am a beginner.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to go to the same page after login in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532141/how-to-go-to-the-same-page-after-login-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

When loading a page, write

```
$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
```

into a user table somewhere.
Then on page load, check if said table has a value, and simply use

`header("Locations:".$userTable['loadedField'])`

after declaring your session.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using Sessions if you write your own session handler. Database sessions offer alot of flexibility and you can preserve the actual session since you have wrote the garbage collection handler. It's not that hard, but is a little out of the scope of a Q & A. I would think this is a perfect case for cookies and can be implemented side by side with your existing sessions. When the user returns to your site, then you can check for the last page url, which your logout routine set a cookie value for. If the resulting page requires them to login, then even better.

More info:
[Sessions](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php)
[Cookies](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

Pretty easy example:

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE["Visited"]))
{
    echo "<h1>Welcome back</h1>";
}
else
{
    echo "<h1>Welcome to the Index</h1>";
    setcookie("Visited", true);
}
```

Comment: thank you ... i m just glad to know that you all community members are of helping nature

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to store the last session page in a file or your database.

The session will be killed when a user logs out (I hope) or when he leaves the page.

As far I know you could make a 'store the last page function' when the user logs out.
However this won't be applied when the user just closes the page. My guess is that you'll have to store the page each time a user browses to another page.

Hope I helped you with that.
Mixxiphoid

Answer (score 0):

Add a `return_to` parameter to the login link and set it to the current page. Catch that parameter on your login page and stick it inside the login form as a hidden value. When processing the login form, if everything went well fire a `header('Location: ' . $_POST['redirect_to']);`

That perhaps is the easiest and most straightforward way, but keep in mind that you have to validate all incoming data, including the `redirect_to` parameter, otherwise there might be a security issue.

~ K

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the actual url of the page a logged in user is visiting in your database (for every single page load, except the logout page) when the user logs in again you have to fetch the last url he visited from database and redirect him :)