# How can I capture the address that user was going to so I can redirect them after login?

Tags: php, symfony1, symfony-1.4

I'm directing users to a page on my site from email (possibly an email client). When they reach the site they are presented with login screen and the address where they were headed is lost.

How can I capture the entire address that they were trying to visit, so that I can redirect them to it once they log in?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to go to the same page after login in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532141/how-to-go-to-the-same-page-after-login-in-php)

Comment: Are you using sf(Doctrine)Guard?

Answer (score 0):

You need to capture the address as you redirect them to the login page, (ie when you check if they are logged in) I'd recommend storing it in a session. A very quick method would be to redirect to `/login.php?from=store.php` for example, however this is not the best way as the `$_GET['from']` could be hijacked to redirect the user somewhere else, which is why I use `$_SESSION` to store this value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I don't know much about Symfony so I will let you know what I do in PHP.

There are a few techniques I use depending on the app.

**Option 1:** I send the user to the page they are to log into, e.g. mydomain.com/landing.php and set a `SESSION` variable with the URL before redirecting to the login form. When the login is performed successfully there is a `header` function that will redirect to the originating page where the logged in user can now interact with the page.

**Option 2:** I create a login function and where there is no login `SESSION` or `COOKIE` the form is called, upon submitting the form using `action="<? echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>` I set a `POST` variable and before any `HTML` tag is called I have something like

```
if(isset($_POST['run_login'])) {
    include('my_login_handler.php');
}
```

This takes care of the login activity and doesn't require any redirection to the target page as it is handled inline.

**Option 3:** Like option 2, I create a login function here there is no login `SESSION` or `COOKIE`, but this time I `POST` the data to `my_login_handler.php` rather than including it. Upon successful authentication to the site I call `header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);` that will redirect to the referring page meaning I don't need to set any special `COOKIES` or `SESSION` variables to handle to redirect back to the target page.

The right option, regardless if it is here or not, is going to depend on your application and what you can/need to do. So have a play with the various suggestions and see what works best in the application you're currently working on.

Good luck!