# Devise - Redirect user to last viewed page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, authentication, devise

I'm designing a portal, where user answers series of questions. Consider there are 10 questions, and user attempts 5 questions and logs out of portal. He logs back in on the next day. Then he should continue from the 6th Question.

I found similar question *[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2532141/how-to-go-to-the-same-page-after-login-in-php)*. But how can it be implemented in rails with devise?

(As every user will have different page viewed last, do I need to store the information in database for every user? or is it still achievable with session/cookies?)

Comment: Store it in the session. It's got nothing to do with devise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The devise wiki has a page on this. You can read it [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-in).

You basically need to define a method called `after_sign_in_path_for`, which redirects to whatever page you want.

As for storing the last completed question, you could store it on a cookie. I would suggest storing it somewhere in the db, and in the cookie. Read from the cookie if possible, if not present, hit the db.